# HP 2050 J510 series alignment issue or cartridge issue?

Tags: printing, printer

[image]

[image]

I just changed to a new black and white cartridge and it is giving me this problem with printing. Please see attached. The words are being cut off. It is happening for everything I print. I'm not sure if this is a cartridge problem or an alignment issue.

I've also printed out and scanned the printed alignment page. you can see it is not very helpful and when I try to align it, the software tells me that "alignment has failed". I never use my color cartridge and it is low. Could that be the problem?

Not sure how to fix this. Could use some pointers if anybody knows about the HP 2050 J510 series. Thanks.

Comment: who's ink did you buy?

Comment: See if [this page helps](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02073861)

Comment: I've fixed it. It will an alignment issue. I had to buy a refill on the color cartridge since the alignment paper depended on the color ink.